# try catch "Cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, try-catch

hi im trying to do a bit of small validation in my code but, when i try to try catch a large area of text (like the one below) i get the error message above the catch which says "Cannot Find Symbol" can someone point me in the right direction in what im doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated

```
try{
    while (option != 0) {     

    }//End Loop      
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {    
    System.out.println("\nNot a number or an integer!\n");
    option = menuSystem();    
}
}
}//End OF Class
```

Comment: `catch(Exception <variableName>)`

Comment: It's a syntax error. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: Also, while posting a question, you can remove the unnecessary parts like the stuff inside the `while` loop which doesn't help in any way

Comment: Why do you have an extra braces after the `//End of class`?

Comment: when i added the try/catch i forgot to move the comment "end of class" to the end, atm its on the end of the main method Edit: edited to make the problem more visable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `try/catch` **is not included** inside any method implementation.

The telltale is that you close curly brace of class just after `catch`'s curly brace! **Where is the curly brace for method?**

Do you have at least a `main` method (or other) containing your code?

For sure, if you start coding just after the class declaration, this will lead to some alerts/errors. Example:

```
public class Job{
  try{ //Unexpected token !!!
  }
  catch(Exception e){

  }
}
```

Your issue is not caused by the missing identifier for exception. 
In that case, you would end up with a "identifer expected" alert.

Besides, remove the last curly brace after the end of class.

Comment: the whole code above is inside a public static void main, just a few lines above the try, sorry i didnt post it in

Comment: @Bunion So your "END OF CLASS" is not well placed. Isn't rather corresponds to end of main method?

Comment: @Bunion i just compiled your code, there were no errors, obviously i have ignored your custom objects. but AFAIS there are  no compile time error specific to java syntax

Comment: its as if its looking for a class when i try and complie i get this error "symbol  : class InputMismachException
location: class Assigment.MenuResults
    }catch(InputMismachException e)
1 error"

Answer (score 1):

The java error **cannot find symbol** occurred when a Compiler does not recognize a class name. The following are the reason for such an error :

1)When a programmer misspelled the name of the class.

2When a programmer do not Imported the class name.

Read [this document](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/cannot-find-symbol.shtml) for more info and check your code again after reading this.

Answer (score 0):

> its as if its looking for a class when i try and complie i get this
>   error "symbol : class InputMismachException location: class
>   Assigment.MenuResults }catch(InputMismachException e) 1 error"

Look at the error properly :

> error "symbol : class InputMismachException location: class 
>   Assigment.MenuResults }catch(InputMismachException e) 1 error"

I assume you are running this code from notepad. if you are i recommend you use an IDE like Eclipse/netbean...
now, coming to the error, it says it cant found **InputMismachException**. you are missing an import statement .

import it in your class like:

```
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;
```